# Slow LINQ performance on Windows 7

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, windows-7, sql-server-express

I have a .net 3.5 application running in production on Windows XP x86 dualcore.
 I have now installed the application on windows 7 x64, quadcore with hyperthreading.
The application is a gui which communicates through WCF with a windows service that communicates with SQLExpress 2008 R2 through Linq2Sql.
We also use Windsor Castle for Dependency Injection/IoC

A certain Linq2Sql statement in the XP-environment takes about 1,5-2 seconds. In windows 7 this statment takes about 5-7 seconds. I have run sql profiler and resource monitor and it seems that the application waits for about 5 seconds and then fires the actual sql-query. so the delay seems to occur below my Datacontext and before the database

I have tried the following:

- changed the connection string to sql authentication
- unplugged the network cable
- uninstalled the antivirus program
- disabled LLMNR
- Removed IPv6 on the network cards
- added transactionscopes with read uncommitted in the code
- tried to add locks (multithreaded environment)
- tried to pin the application to one cpu
- run as admin

My theory is that something is timing out, but what?!?

Comment: What's the LINQ statement in question?

Comment: You have to isolate the code that took your time. Add logging statements to some strategic places to see where its hanging.

Comment: Have you tried compiled queries?

Comment: The query in question is a really simple select where id=
I have added logging and it shows that it is the actual request to the database that takes time.

I haven't tried compiled queries, but if it is ok on XP I don't see why I would need it on Win 7

Comment: @Manatherin: I uninstalled the Antivirus (with firewall) and then the firewall in windows was disabled. So, no...

Comment: @GertArnold it seems that most queries are slow (I haven't dug really exactly which are fast and which are slow), especially those that hit the main table of the domain. The query in question is executed by itself but it is a multithreaded environment... However in the profiling of the database no other queries are seen. So it's like dead quiet for about 2 seconds and then the query in question bombards the database (my guesstimate around 100 queries). Your last statement could certainly be true but how do I avoid it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting the target platform to x86 instead of AnyCPU the program behaves as expected. So the problem seems to be that Linq2Sql and x64 doesn't really play together. I don't know if we can get it as a bug but it behaves bad any way.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are going to have to slowly add in your code to find the issue - divide and conquer.

If it is the actual request to the database that is taking the time, then this isn't actually related to your application on Win 7 vs Win XP.  How fast does this query take when firing it against the database directly?  If this is fast, move up the call stack...

How fast is the Windows Service?  Can you make a request to it, and see how fast that is?

How fast is the WCF layer?  Can you hit it directly and see it is slow?  Then you have found your culprit.

Next, on to your UI - is it slow if you make a little test app that exercises the bottom of the application?  If not, keep moving up.

In the end, some of this can easily be accomplished by adding logging statements from the top to the bottom, so you can isolate the issue, just like suggested by @Jan

Comment: I did most of that and I came to the conclusion that all the time lays in the request to the database. The SQL profiling of the queries in the database shows that the query wouldn't take more than one second to execute. It is also seen in the CPU-graph of the database that it goes up around one second before the response is recevied

Comment: Can you use SQL Profiler to see what is happening on the database server during the "hang" you experience in the App?  Maybe Win 7 connects or communicates differently than Win XP.

Comment: If I run SQL Profiler I can see a 4 second total quietness on Windows 7, this does not appear on Windows XP. I also tested to use a database on Windows XP (with the same data) and the behaviour is the same. If i run the application on XP-XP no waiting, if I run Win7-XP same behaviour as Win7-Win7. So it concludes that is is not the database itself but somewhere between the database and the application. There is something on Windows 7 that steals the time...

Comment: I also tried to make a new linq project with the same database, but I can't reporoduce the problems there. So it is probably in the code, now I suspect Castle Windsor, since I have had problems with it before on Windows 7

Comment: Can you repro this issue while your application is in the debugger?  Since you have a 4 second lag, you may be able to find it by just clicking pause during the lag.

Comment: I think otherwise, you are just going to have to [Measure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2011/09/20/measure.aspx) at increasing granularity to find the problem.

Comment: I have tried to do some remote debugging but it seems to get lost since I can't really step into the Linq calls. And of course I'm on a XP-box... I'm running dotTrace now and it shows that it is the acual Linq calls that takes time but I have to set it up so I can step into the Linq calls to see more. I'm pretty ceratin that is some kind of deadlock due to faster cpu:s and more cores (which is strange since it behaves the same running on just one core)

Comment: It seems that it gets stuck at: var fnMaterialize = (Delegate)dm.CreateDelegate(fnMatType); ObjectReaderCompiler.cs in SqlClient for Linq (I downloaded the sources from MS and if I break the debugger this is where my current thread ends up)

Comment: I did some testing and I have a class that have about 17 inheritancemappings and if I reduce to 7 the performance goes from 7 seconds to about 2 when I run my test programs

Comment: It seems that if you have an baseclass where there is a lot of classes inhereting that baseclass (direct or indirect) the performance goes down. If you add a property on the baseclass this is not very well treated on the Win 7 machine. You can see time-differences when I have around 10 subclasses (deepest tree is 3 subclasses) and 8 properties on the baseclass. It is probably when win 7 tries to merge all the classes that something goes wrong.

Comment: I just found this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996488/net-linq-to-sql-performance-issue-with-inherited-discriminators), and it aligns closely with your situation.  Unfortunately, the suggested answer is to get rid of the inheritance.

Comment: yes, thanks I have seen that question as well. Removing the inheritance is a real worst case scenario.  If I send the raw sql-query (the query generated by Linq) from the datacontext with ExecuteQuery the time drops from 7 seconds to 1 second, but the performance is still worse than on XP (where it drops from 1 sec to 400 ms). I'm going to contact Microsoft Support to see if I can get this confirmed as a bug in .Net 3.5.1 for Win7 because something is definitely wrong.

Comment: Just an update. We realized that is probably some kind of memory issue. If we run our test program with 8 threads we have a virtual memory usage of around 3 GB on Win 7 but only 80 MB on XP...

The issue is handled by Microsoft Support at the moment...