# Linq-to-SQL very slow materialization

Tags: c#, performance, linq-to-sql

I am experiencing the bad loading time of my `.aspx` pages and I am currently trying to optimize it. First I used `Visual Studio Performance Analyzer` and `SQL Server Profiler` to find slow places, then I put `Stopwatch`es directly in my code.

Do not quite understand what is going on, but it looks like the slowest method in the whole app is the materialization method, but it is slow ONLY for three small tables:

```
internal T[] GetTableAsArray<T>() where T : class
{
    return dataContext.GetTable<T>().ToArray();
}
```

Fourth table is okay. `SQL Server Profiler` shows zero `Duration` of SQL queries, but my `Stopwatch` shows 677ms, 884ms, 355ms and 8ms. All tables are ~50 rows and ~7 columns.

Any ideas? Where should I dig?

Comment: "small" how? How many records are there? Why are you calling `ToArray()` by the way, out of curiosity? It's often good practice to iterate in a way that allows linq-to-sql to defer the loading.

Comment: Small is ~50 rows and ~7 columns of simple data. I found the reason of the slow down, and unfortunately for me, it requires to heavily redesign my app in order to fix this.

Comment: I added it as answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Sirs, the complicated inheritance is the answer. The same problem is described here: [.NET Linq to SQL Performance Issue with Inherited Discriminators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4996488/net-linq-to-sql-performance-issue-with-inherited-discriminators). My slow tables have children, fast tables haven't.